# How to utilize all of the CPU cores in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I've noticed that it's often the case that algorithms inside [MAGE](https://memgraph.com/docs/mage) are running for a longer period of time but using only one CPU core. I'd like to know how to leverage all available cores on the system? I've checked the docs, but I didn't find any config flags that would could be used.

Comment: This is weird cause their docs claim it does use all the cores.  Are you running in a container or something or a VM that is virtually limiting your resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I'm the co-founder and CTO at Memgraph

All algorithms inside `mage` have serial implementations in the first place. Parallel (and/or concurrent) code can often be tricky to get correct and more performant than serial code. But, the Memgraph team aims to provide parallel implementations for every algorithm inside `mage`. In other words, each algorithm requires a specific implementation to use all available resources on the server. In addition, there are [Memgraph cuGraph implementations](https://github.com/memgraph/mage/tree/main/cpp/cugraph_module) of some algorithms that utilize the GPU attached to the server (if there is one).

More broadly, the execution of a single query inside Memgraph is a single thread (at the time of writing, 2023-07-02). There is a plan to support "**intra**query" parallelization, but that will also be limited to specific Cypher clauses. Specific `mage` algorithms will always require special care to make them leverage all available compute resources.